# Order alphabetically, but with first all active instances, and in the end the inactive instances

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have some instances which I would like to filter alphabetically. However inactive instances (instance.inactive) should be on the end.

How can I achieve this?

EDIT:
In my model I have a property to get the previous and next:

```
@property
def previous(self):
    '''
    Return the previous
    '''
    qs = self.__class__.objects.filter(name__lt=self.name).order_by('-name')[:1]
    if qs:
        return qs[0]
    else: 
        return None
```

Now I want to find next and previous but with the inactive ones 'in the end'

Comment: note that name and active are two different columns, so not a duplicate!

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to do it by providing ordering arguments to this model's Meta class. I think something like this should work:

```
class Meta:
    ordering = ['title', 'inactive']
```

Or you can pass it to order_by queryset method.

```
YourModel.objects.order_by('title', 'inactive')
```

('title' is the field that you use for alphabetical filtering)

Answer (score 2):

Okay, this is how I solved it now. I thought it would be possible with just one query, but likely not:

```
    qs = self.__class__.objects.filter(name__lt=self.name, user_active=self.user_active).order_by('-name')[:1]
    if qs:
        return qs[0]
    else:
        switched_user_active = not self.user_active
        qs = self.__class__.objects.filter(user_active=switched_user_active).order_by('-name')[:1]
        return qs[0] if qs else None
```

Thanks for the answers, as those pointed me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

Show some code of your model.

Assuming model is called instance and it has a field called status. You want to order the instances by another field called 'name'.

```
qs = Instance.objects.exclude(status='inactive').order_by('name') | Instance.objects.filter(status='inactive')
```

Another way to solve this is to understand how Case works when Whens. Here is the link to documentation. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#case

Comment: Hmm, the way you decribed here does not work for me... The pipe does not put the inactive ones at the end.